# Android ExoPlayer What Does "prepare()" Exactly Do?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

The only difference I notice is that, if I call `prepare()` before `play()`, I will see the the process indicator and it pre-loads data in the `PlayerView`, besides that I can't tell the difference if I just call `play()` without `prepare()`.

Also the documentation says nothing: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html

```
public void prepare()

Description copied from interface: Player

Prepares the player.    //<- ???

Specified by:
prepare in interface Player
```

Comment: `prepare` tells the player to acquire all the resources required for playback

Comment: @Usama Altaf What's the advantages of calling it before `play()`?

Comment: It starts loading file from the source (filling the buffer). You might not notice it when playing a local file but for remote streams it will reduce initial delay.

Comment: @Pawel That make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some clue in the [javadoc](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html#prepare())

> This will move the player out of idle state and the player will start loading media and acquire resources needed for playback.

There is also another case where you want to call prepare.

> Failed or stopped playbacks can be retried by calling `ExoPlayer.prepare`
> [Source](https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html#playback-errors)